# Unable to start modules in QGIS GRASS plugin (GNU/Linux Debian)

Tags: grass-gis, qgis-plugins, qgis-2, debian

Recently, the Toolbox of QGIS GRASS plugin can't find modules in my GNU/Linux Debian. When I click on any module, the toolbox reports the message: Cannot find module x.xxx and, after, I have the dialog window options totally empty (see image below).

[image]

My system worked nicely until yesterday.

To solve this problem (in my system recently actualized; with QGIS v. 2.8), I uninstall and install QGIS-GRASS system, including configuration files, erase my **.qgis2** home and **.grassrc6** (I modified my **.bashrc** too for adapting these changes) files. Nothing took effect.

I found out that the GRASS-QGIS modules are in **/usr/share/qgis/grass/modules**. My question is: **How can I get my bindings to this path again?**

**Note**: GRASS Console and GRASS commands of Processing Toolbox work well; apparently. However, I would like using the Toolbox of QGIS GRASS plugin again for saving time and it can use my already created work spaces.

Comment: The QGIS-GRASS-plugin still requires GRASS GIS 6 - is it installed? (A crowdfunding campaign is ongoing to fund support for G7)

Comment: Yes, it is installed and works well in GRASS Console; as I found recently (see the [image](http://postimg.org/image/47hztw31x/)). However, Modules in Modules List have disappeared.

Comment: I've just seen a flag from you requesting that this be migrated to [unix.se].  Unfortunately, it is too old to migrate (that must be done within 60 days of the question being asked I think) so I recommend that you delete it here, and re-word it to post it as a new question on [unix.se].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Today (3 and half months later), I solved my problem with the update to new 2.10 (Pisa) version of QGIS.

Comment: Well, this is not a real solution. I suffer from the same problem, but I would like to keep 2.8 for compatibility reasons. So your original question is not answered.